# How to drain a brake booster

Tags: brakes, master-cylinder, brake-booster

I improperly installed a master cylinder. This punctured a hole in the cylinder. I didn't realize this until I pumped a gallon of brake fluid into my booster. How do I get it out?

2014 jeep wrangler unlimited rubicon

Comment: Buy a new one. If you punctured the membrane then it won't work. And the chances of you correctly replacing the membrane... That is assuming you can get a new membrane.

Comment: I am getting a new master cylinder, but the brake booster still seems to function ok. It's just oozing with brake fluid.

Comment: How did you test the booster to know it is functioning ok?

Comment: @SolarMike do you think I could have damaged it too? It was brand new. I'm not sure how to test it, but if I actuate the plunger the fluid seems to suck back and forth between the inner chamber.

Comment: Brake boosters don’t move fluid, they work on air pressure difference...

Comment: @SolarMike right, but I flooded it with fluid that was leaking from my master cylinder. I pumped the brakes to bleed the calipers, but instead of fluid going through the brake lines it all went into the booster. A lot of fluid. Now I'm just trying to get that fluid out.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to remove the booster from the fire wall of the vehicle, then drain it out, then use some acetone to clean it out. Let it dry, then re-install. If it continues to work correctly, you're in business. If not, you'll need to buy a new one or at the very least, one from a wrecking yard as a replacement. Unfortunately, you probably won't know if it's still going to work until you get it back installed. More than likely, there will be either two or four bolts on the fire wall. Could be inside the passenger cabin to get access or might be in the engine compartment. You'll also need to disconnect the booster from the brake pedal, but that's usually just a rod with a pin/clip arrangement. Really not anything too difficult, but can be a pain in the butt on some models (depending on access space).

Comment: It is out of the vehicle. I put the old one back in. The new booster is completely soaked. I also read I could use isopropyl alcohol to clean it out. However, fluid seems to be retained inside an inner chamber that I can't clean. If I plunge the booster, some of the fluid seeps back into the visible area, but I just don't think I can clean this well enough.

Comment: @JoshC. - If you can dilute the brake fluid enough with IPA, the IPA will then evaporate over time and will just be sucked into and burned through the engine without detriment. The way to dilute the brake fluid is to just fill it up with IPA, swish it around some, then drain as much as you can out, through whatever means short of puncturing something. Do this *several times*. I should then be in pretty good shape.

Comment: I think the IPA worked. I went through 2 32oz bottles of IPA. I no longer hear a sloshing sound from inside the booster, so I went ahead and installed it. However, I hears a squeak when I release the brake pedal. I wonder if the IPA stripped some of the lubrication from the booster. Is there away I can lubricate it?