# White smoke from exhaust after brake job

Tags: brakes, exhaust, jeep, smoke

I attempted (and failed) to replace my master cylinder and brake booster. I ended up putting a lot of brake fluid into my new booster before I realized it. (In fact, in an attempt to determine the problem I turned the engine on a few times. I now realize this was an additional mistake.)

So I put the old booster and cylinder back on and began bleeding my brake lines but noticed my brake lights were staying on. I started the engine in hopes it might correct the issue and a tremendous amount of white smoke came out of the exhaust pipe.

I suspect when I started the engine the first time I sucked fluid from the cylinder that was leaking into the engine. I'm not sure what to do now.

2014 jeep Wrangler unlimited Rubicon

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think they're any connection between the brake fluid reservoir and the commission chamber. If that's true, there's no way fluid would have gone there unless you put it on the wrong spot. In any case, please add the year/make/model of the vehicle to your post.

Comment: See https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/70063/10976

Comment: @kyle_engineer, done.

Comment: @solar_mike. I have put the old booster and cylinder on, which were operating correctly before the job. This brake booster isn't flooded with brake fluid.

Comment: @kyle_engineer well, he filled the the brake booster with brake fluid. From there it went through the vacuum tube and inlet manifold into the engine..

Comment: @Martin now that I have the old booster and master cylinder on do I just run the engine until the fluid is burned off?

Comment: @JoshC. I don't know. Nobody will give you a guarantee that this won't damage engine, catalyst nor health. In your case I would try somehow to clean of most of it, perform an oil change and hope for the best.

Comment: @Martin, what things should I consider to clean what I can? (I'm staying away from the fumes as much as possible.)

Comment: @JoshC. honestly, I have no idea and don't feel ready to give you a reasonable answer. The only helpful thought I have is that you should perform an oil change asap, ideally perform additional oil changes afterwards to ensure that all contamination get cleaned away.

Comment: I am changing the oil today. I may do another one in a week or so. I know this is a pretty messed up situation. I'm just trying to make the best of it.

Comment: @JoshC. good luck then!

Comment: The engine sounds better since the oil change. I prior to the oil change I let the engine idle for a long while revving it occasionally. Yesterday evening I got it all put back together and took it for a spin. The brakes feel great. I was still blowing some white smoke when accelerating but that quickly cleared up. It seems to be all good today.